# Assignment of values to variables while performing operations?

Tags: bash, shell, variable-assignment, assign, assignment-operator

Can anyone please tell me how I should go about assigning the value of the square root of a number to a variable in Bash?

This is my code.

```
#!/bin/bash
a=5
c=sqrt"($a)"|bc -l
echo "$c"
```

When executed, it displays nothing

However, I observe that when the following is executed,

```
#!/bin/bash
a=5
echo sqrt"($a)"|bc -l
```

I get an answer

```
2.23606797749978969640
```

Can someone tell me as to how I could bind the value of the square root of a to c?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
c=$(bc -l <<< "sqrt($a)")
```

or

```
c=$(echo "sqrt($a)" | bc -l)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to take the first string and pipe it through `bc` putting the result in `c`. The following works (as mentioned by [John Kugelman](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52670247/revisions)):

```
#!/bin/bash
a=5
c=$(echo sqrt"($a)" | bc -l)
echo "$c"
```